# PHP-version on Raspberry Pi different in phpinfo()

Tags: raspbian, php, apache-httpd, mysql

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 where I want to run my backend for an application on. This needs php 5.6 to run correctly, otherwise it will just not work. I installed PHP 5.6 on this Raspberry Pi, but now I have the problem that when I do `php -v` on the Command Line it will say `PHP 5.6.13 (cli) (built: Dec  1 2015 09:39:07)`.

When I do `phpinfo()` it will give me `PHP Version 5.4.45-0+deb7u2` (and also 5.4 for all other php-related plugins/libraries/extensions, no '5.6' is found on that page.

I tried to completely install php 5.6 from scratch, but that also didn't fix the problem.

For my backend to run the apache needs PHP 5.6. I hope someone knows how to solve this problem and can help me with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify what version of Raspbian you are running, however,  Raspbian Jessie shows PHP 5.6.14 available via **apt-get**. I used the following command to determine this:

```
sudo apt-cache policy php5
```

It can be installed with the following command

```
sudo apt-get -y install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

To make Apache recognize the updated version you will need to restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

You can test this with the same `phpinfo();` command you used before.

Comment: I will install Jessie and then try what you said. Right now it is running Wheezy.

Comment: Your solution seems to be working. Both the Command Line and `phpinfo()` show `5.6.14-0+deb8u1`. Now I can finally continue setting up my backend. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have the problem that you have two different versions installed and the one you want to use is not the one that is being selected. A quick search brought up the SE Q&A: [is there a tool to manage multiple installations of php on one machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640677/is-there-a-tool-to-manage-multiple-installations-of-php-on-one-machine-e-g-to#10954197) There are several answers including phpbrew but it isn't clear to me - a non-PHP user - which, if any will suite your circumstances, one simple bash script that I looked at seemed possibly of use for the RPi. It was [php-switch](https://github.com/memnuniyetsizim/php-switch) on Github.