# I compiled and installed PHP7 but still see 5

Tags: php

After a lot of problems I tried building my own LAMP server, I have NGINX on it, PHP 5.4, MySQL (as I could not get mariadb to work no matter the guide) and it's running Raspbian Wheezy.

Anyway, I followed the instructions here: [How can I install PHP 5.6 (instead of 5.4)?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32743/how-can-i-install-php-5-6-instead-of-5-4)
but replaced everything with the latest 7 stable version. After the `xm12lib` error was corrected I had no other issues. It said it installed successfully, but on my phpinfo page I'm still seeing the original 5.4 release. Any idea how to correct?

Comment: This may help http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40591/php-version-on-raspberry-pi-different-in-phpinfo/40593#40593. I am betting that you installed CLI PHP which you can confirm by running php -v from the command prompt. But you have not installed the PHP 7 module for apache.

Answer (score -1):

Compiling binaries is a hassle. I prefer `apt` and reserve compilation as a last resort.

Add this line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://repozytorium.mati75.eu/raspbian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

Then update using

```
apt-get update
```

Then install `php7` using

```
apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-opcache
```

<sub>Additional info: Take note that adding repositories aside from official ones may present some security risk. But, I hand picked that one so it should be safe.</sub>

Comment: You should mention that this can be a major security issue (i.e. installing preconfigured binaries from an unknown source).

Comment: I don't get what is funny